# Am i creating a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

I have a JavaScript closure which I keep recreating throughout the life time of my web application (single full-ajax page).

I would like to know if it's creating a memory leak.

Here is an example [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bqqjU/)

The code in question:

```
function CreateLinks() {

    var ul = $("<ul></ul>").appendTo('div#links');

    for (var i in myLinks) {

        var li = $('<li>' + myLinks[i].name + '</li>').appendTo(ul);

        //closure starts here
        (function (value) {
            li.click(function (e) {
                $('div#info').append('<label>' + value + '</label><br />');
                RecreateLinks();
            });
        })(myLinks[i].value);

    }
}
```

Comment: whats the point of making a closure there? why not say `var value = myLinks[i].value;` and run the code directly?

Comment: @Jacob: ohh i see. you mean `myLinks[i].value`, right.

Comment: no memory is leaked in the above code. But it is too complicated way of solving the problem

Comment: The closure has a purpose, test and compare [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bqqjU/1/) against the one in my question... this one only outputs "tres" for all links.

Comment: i is not index it is the property name.

Comment: @Amareswar if you have a better solution, please propose it :)

Comment: Does `RecreateLinks()` do the same thing again? Sounds like it :)

Comment: @Jack yes `RecreateLinks()` removes all the links and calls `CreateLinks()` again... this happens many times throughout the lifetime of my app.

Comment: Couldn't you put the call in a `setInterval(method, 10);` and watch your OS statistics and see if memory increases for your browser application? I know there are more things going on than just the closure, but jQuery is pretty memory efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be okay IF you make sure that you avoid binding multiple `click` handlers in the `RecreateLinks()` function; this can be done by explicitly unbinding existing ones, removing the DOM nodes or making sure that you won't be adding multiple `click` handlers.

Browsers are getting better at memory allocation strategies, but you shouldn't assume too much. If memory usage is a big concern, try to avoid creating too many closures of which you're not sure they will get garbage collected. One such approach is to use `.data()` to store your value object and then use a generic click handler instead of a closure.

Profiling JavaScript is not so simple; Chrome does have a Profile tool that can monitor CPU and data performance. This can give you a pretty good gauge on the expected memory consumption, but Chrome is not all browsers, keep that in mind.

Comment: aren't the closures only referenced by the `li` elements which are removed in `RecreateLinks()` anyway?

Comment: I can't access `li` click handlers from `RecreateLinks()`. Maybe you could update the jsfiddle and show me what you mean.

Comment: @capdragon removing the elements themselves would also be fine. Unless you're sure that you never bind a click event multiple times, which reminds me that you could also use .one()

Comment: @capdragon added another suggestion you could adopt.

Comment: @Jack I appreciate your suggestions(+1). Though, There is no shortage of workarounds or solutions. I simply want to know if the closure is creating a memory leak. And I want some evidence to prove it and/or methodology where I can see for myself.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how smart the browser is, it may be better to have "myLinks[i].value" an attribute on your `<li>` rather than passed via closure. Certain dumb browsers have issues collecting garbage when an event handler references a variable from outside it's scope. JavaScript and DOM run two different GC and the JS one doesn't realize the DOM element/eventhandler is gone and that the variable is no longer in use. This issue may be cleared up by properly removing the event handler via javascript rather than just disposing of the element which it is attached to.

Something akin to:

```
li.attr('lvalue',myLinks[i].value);
...
var value = $(this).attr('lvalue');
```

This setup would also allow you to use

```
$('#links > ul > li').live('click',function(){...});
```

Which would remove the need for adding individual events each time.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the suggestion, this would work... Thing is `myLinks[i].value` is a pretty big object in my application. That is, it's an object with many properties and methods. I made it simple here just as an example. I suppose it wouldn't be good to map out every property/method to an li attribute.

Comment: @capdragon you could use a js object in your code, and an id to that object on the li tag.

Comment: you're right, I suppose that is another way. Though, I really just want to know if the closure is creating a memory leak. And I want some evidence to prove it and/or methodology where I can see for myself.

Comment: I wish such tools existed, from my experience tracking memory or cpu usage of a webpage is near impossible.